# text/html 404 notFound when need to using image background in angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to use the image for background in span tag in angular :

```
.iti-flag {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-image: url("src/assets/img/flags/flags.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  background-position: 20px 0;
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
  only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
  only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2 / 1),
  only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
  only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi),
  only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) {
  .iti-flag {
    background-image: url("src/assets/img/flags/flags.png");
  }
}
```

This is my span tag that want to image for background :

```
 <span [class]="'iti-flag iti-flag-selected ' + selectedCountry.flagClass" matPrefix></span>
```

But in network tab I track that, it loaded by text/plain format and I need to show that image by image format.

**Whats the problem? How can i solve this problem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `src` from you path and try like this.

```
background-image: url("/assets/img/flags/flags.png");
```